# Add a existing file to folder

Tags: c#

I am beginner in c#. In my project, the user selects a Image file through OpenFileDialog box. When he/she selects the image file I am running the back code something like this:

```
File.Copy(SourceFilePath, DestinationFilePath);
```

The problem with the above code is that it is throwing error whenever the user is trying to add a existing image file. To avoid this error, I changed my code to the below one:

```
if (File.Exists(DestinationFilePath))
{
     intCount++;
     File.Copy(SourceFilePath,TemporaryFilePath);
     File.Copy(TemporaryFilePath, DestinationFilePath + intCount.ToString());
     File.Delete(TemporaryFilePath);                                
}
else
{
     File.Copy(SourceFilePath, DestinationFilePath);
}
```

The problem in the above code is that it is adding the `intCount` value at the very end of the image file like `image.gif1` which is changing the file extension. How to add a counter to image file paths?

And I think the approach I am using here to check the existing file is not correct way of doing.

Update: **Answer** :-

```
        int intCount = 1;
        while (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + DirectoryPath + strPath))
        {
            strPath = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strPath) + intLarge.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(strPath);
            intCount++;
        }
        intCount = 1;
```

Comment: You can use the `Path` class to manipulate file names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string destinationfilename)
```

add `int` to it and the add the extension to it which you can get by

```
Path.GetExtension(string destinationfilename)
```

Comment: It is showing error -- "The process cannot access the file 'filePath' because it is being used by another process." to your first post method.

Answer (score 2):

```
private string GetIndexedFilePath(string path, int index)
{
   var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
   var oldFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
   var extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
   var indexedFileName = String.Format("{0}_{1}{2}", oldFileName, index, extension);
   return Path.Combine(directoryName, indexedFileName);
}
```

Btw keep in mind, that after renaming file to something like "file_2.gif" you still can have name conflict with already existing file in target directory.

```
string destinationPath;
int index = 0;
do
{
    destinationPath = GetIndexedFilePath(path, ++index);
}
while(File.Exists(destinationPath));
// Copy file to destinationPath
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
DestinationFilePath + intCount.ToString()
```

You can use:

```
intCount.ToString() + DestinationFilePath
```

Which will add it to the start, resulting in `1image.gif`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to just to create a new file path.

The below function will give image.gif with the count of 1 to be image1.gif

```
private string GetIncrementedFilePath(string orginalFilePath, int count)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(orginalFilePath);
    var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(orginalFilePath);
    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(orginalFilePath);

    var newFullPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}{3}", directory, fileName, count, extension);

    return newFullPath;
}
```

Please note that Path.GetExension will give you '.gif' not 'gif'

```
// Summary:
//     Returns the extension of the specified path string.
//
// Parameters:
//   path:
//     The path string from which to get the extension.
//
// Returns:
//     A System.String containing the extension of the specified path (including
//     the "."), null, or System.String.Empty. If path is null, GetExtension returns
//     null. If path does not have extension information, GetExtension returns Empty.
//
// Exceptions:
//   System.ArgumentException:
//     path contains one or more of the invalid characters defined in System.IO.Path.GetInvalidPathChars().
public static string GetExtension(string path);
```

If you want to know if a file exists then there is a function built into .NET to do that.

```
// Summary:
//     Determines whether the specified file exists.
//
// Parameters:
//   path:
//     The file to check.
//
// Returns:
//     true if the caller has the required permissions and path contains the name
//     of an existing file; otherwise, false. This method also returns false if
//     path is null, an invalid path, or a zero-length string. If the caller does
//     not have sufficient permissions to read the specified file, no exception
//     is thrown and the method returns false regardless of the existence of path.
File.Exists(path);
```

Comment: Thank you for response, what if the user selects again the existing file.. (I am checking which will take time)

Comment: I am assuming that is why you have the count.  If you increment it by 2 you get image2.gif.  There is also a function called File.Exists where you can check if the file exists and if it does then delete the previous or increment the count.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the the class `Path` to perform operations on `System.String` instances that contain file or directory name information to separate a string representing a file name from its extension

Example

```
string Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(DestinationFilePath); //Get the file name excluding its extension
string Extension = Path.GetExtension(DestinationFilePath); //Declare a new string representing the extension of the file
File.Copy(TemporaryFilePath,  DestinationFilePath.Replace(Path.GetFileName(DestinationFilePath), "") + Name + intCount.ToString() + Extension); //Copy from TemporaryFilePath to DestinationFilePath appending a number after the string then the Extension we gathered first
```

The example posted above will copy a file name of for example `TemporaryFilePath\File_Name.(Extension)` to `DestinationFilePath\File_Name (intCount).(Extension)` where `(intCount)` represents a number and `(Extension)` represnts the extension of the file. So, the final appearance of the file name will look like the following if `intCount` is equal to `1` and the `Extension` is `.exe`

- `DestinationFilePath\File_Name 1.exe`

Thanks,

 I hope you find this helpful :)